# Angular 7 - Pass url params to route, from separate app/server

Tags: angular, http, parameters, routes

I have an Angular 7 app, and a need to navigate to this app from an older legacy system.

This older system still uses JSP pages, but i can use jQuery to call the new Angular 7 app.

The ask is to navigate to the Angular app and have fields/views be pre-populated or filtered based on parameters passed in the url from the legacy screen.

So, my question is, how do i call an Angular route url such as `http://localhost:8080/myScreen` and provide it url params from a completely separate application screen to then be used inside the screens component to pre-filter data?

Is it some simple solution of using url params like: `http://localhostl:8080/myScreen?param1=Hello&param2=World`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use ActivatedRoute by

**MyScreenComponent.ts**

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit()
   const {param1,param2} = this.route.snapshot.params;
   //do what you want with the params
}
```

**Have your route configured as**

`{ path: 'myScreen/:param1/:param2', component: MyScreenComponent }`

You may change the code above to use queryParams if that's what you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('BComponent::ngOnInit');

    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      fname: 'default fname',
      lname: 'default lname'
    });

    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.myForm.setValue({
        fname: params['param1'],
        lname: params['param2']
      })
    });
  }
```

here the myForm is populated from queryParams.

Check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ymbfo3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fb%2Fb.component.ts).